# How to use a string as a primary key in MVC 3 Entity Framework 4.1 Code First?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I'm using the latest and greatest Entity Framework Code First and I'm running into a scenario where I want one of my classes to use a string for the primary key.  I had to manually add the key to the Create View (by default it treats it like an identity).  However, when I try to create a new **MyAccount**, I get the error below.  I'm using the MVC Scaffolder Repository pattern to build the MyAccountController.  Your wisdom I seek with great appreciation.

### Model:

```
public class MyAccount 
{
    [Key, Required, MaxLength(80), Display(Name = "User name")]   
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required, DataType(DataType.EmailAddress), MaxLength(100), Display(Name = "Email address")]   
    public string Email { get; set; } 
}
```

### View:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <legend>MyAccount</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)%>
        </div>
        <%: Html.Partial("CreateOrEdit", Model) %>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
<% } %>
```

### Controller:

```
    //
    // GET: /MyAccount/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /MyAccount/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MyAccount myaccount)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            myaccountRepository.InsertOrUpdate(myaccount);
            myaccountRepository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        } else {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

### Repository:

```
public class MyAccountRepository : IMyAccountRepository
{
    Par4ScoreContext context = new Par4ScoreContext();

    public IQueryable<MyAccount> All
    {
        get { return context.MyAccounts; }
    }

    public IQueryable<MyAccount> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<MyAccount, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<MyAccount> query = context.MyAccounts;
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties) {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }
        return query;
    }

    public MyAccount Find(string id)
    {
        return context.MyAccounts.Find(id);
    }

    public void InsertOrUpdate(MyAccount myaccount)
    {
        if (myaccount.UserName == default(string)) {
            // New entity
            context.MyAccounts.Add(myaccount);
        } else {
            // Existing entity
            context.Entry(myaccount).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }

    public void Delete(string id)
    {
        var myaccount = context.MyAccounts.Find(id);
        context.MyAccounts.Remove(myaccount);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public interface IMyAccountRepository
{
    IQueryable<PlayerAccount> All { get; }
    IQueryable<PlayerAccount> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<MyAccount, object>>[] includeProperties);
    MyAccount Find(string id);
    void InsertOrUpdate(MyAccount playeraccount);
    void Delete(string id);
    void Save();
}
```

### Error in MyAccountRepository.Save():

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException was unhandled by user code:  
"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries."
StackTrace:
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
at MyProject.Models.MyAccountRepository.Save()
```

....

```
InnerException: System.Data.OptimisticConcurrencyException
Message=Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0).    
Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
Source=System.Data.Entity
StackTrace:
    at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ValidateRowsAffected(Int64 rowsAffected, UpdateCommand source)
    at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
    at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
    at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: Can you show the controller action?  Do you have a form element in your view?

Comment: Yes I have a form element, I was just trying to show the control I added for the UserName.  I'll add the Controller Action now.

Comment: try changing `playeraccount.UserName == default(string)` in your repository to `string.IsNulOrEmpty(playeraccount.UserName)`

Comment: Eranga, you were close.  I needed a seperate Update and Create method for my Repository class.  If you Answer the question rather than comment than I can give you credit.

Comment: you can actually vote up comments as well.

Comment: I want to mark the question as answered though.  The trick is seperating the Update and the Delete into seperate methods, and Eranga led me right to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MVC model binder will assign an empty string to `UserName` you can check whether its new or not by using `string.IsNulOrEmpty(playeraccount.UserName)`. You can use [IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) if you treat spaces as empty.

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(MyAccount myaccount)
{
    if (string.IsNulOrEmpty(myaccount.UserName)) {
        // New entity
        context.MyAccounts.Add(myaccount);
    } else {
        // Existing entity
        context.Entry(myaccount).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```